# Powershell - GUI won't work when Exchange Online is connected

Tags: powershell

Can anyone please tell me, why following simple script won't work?

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-ExchangeOnline -credential $cred -ShowBanner:$false

#Fenstergröße
$pshost = get-host
$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui
$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
$newsize.height = 3000
$newsize.width = 130
$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
$newsize = $pswindow.windowsize
$newsize.height = 43
$newsize.width = 130
$pswindow.windowsize = $newsize

#gui
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text = "Benutzername"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,150)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter"){
        $Script:User = $objUserTB.text;
        $objForm.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK;
        $objForm.Close()
    }
})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){
    $objForm.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel;
    $objForm.Close()
}})

#Eingabefeld
$objLabelUser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabelUser.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,17) 
$objLabelUser.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(81,20) 
$objLabelUser.Text = "Benutzername:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabelUser)
$objUserTB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objUserTB.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(105,15)
$objUserTB.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170,30)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objUserTB)

#Buttons
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,60)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(85,25)
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$OKButton.Add_Click({
    $Script:User = $objUserTB.Text;
    $objForm.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK;
    $objForm.Close()
})

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Text = "Abbrechen"
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,60) 
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(85,25)
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
$CancelButton.Add_Click({
    $objForm.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel;
    $objForm.Close()
})

$guires = $objForm.ShowDialog()
if($guires -eq "Cancel"){exit 1}

$user

clv $user,$guires -ea 0

write-host "Zum Beenden Enter drücken."
read-host
```

It works in ISE, but not when running the script via right click. No Error is displayed and when I comment the first two lines out, the script works. I'm banging my head against the wall, but this doesn't help either.

I've tried different systems and wrote the GUI new from scratch. I should only display a simple GUI with one field for a username and write the username in a variable, but when I run the script via right click, the Powershell window closes after a few seconds, without any error displayed.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works the same as a script with right click as it does pasting into powershell or ISE.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the ExchangenOnlineManagement module and now the scripts runs smoothly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).